electronic equipment test with python to generate a nice report
I seem not to be able to find the right search keywords to solve that problem myself.
The keywords "python test report html" only provides a lot of references to tests, that test python itself. Basically software / unit tests.
But I run some GPIB / SCIPI tests on my test equipment and want to format these results in a way I can store online or print as a pdf.
Question: Is there a library for python that takes logical and numeric minimum, maximum and result as input, formats that as a table, marking good and bad values and compiles that into an html report? If it then could add some chapters and descriptive headlines, it would be perfect.
Or do I completely misunderstand pytest?
Thanks!
enter image description here

Do you mean like coverage?
